# Reflection.TargetException problem

Tags: c#, reflection

I want the EmployeeNumber property for an Employee to only be set by the database, but I need to be able to set the value for unit testing. Which is why I made the helper code below.

Can someone help me troubleshoot & fix this?

Cheers,
Berryl

## Helper Code

```
public static void SetEmployeeNumberFor(Employee employee, EmployeeNumber employeeNumber)
    {
        var empNumberProperty = employee.GetType().GetProperty("EmployeeNumber", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        Check.Invariant(empNumberProperty != null);
        Check.Invariant(empNumberProperty.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(EmployeeNumber)));

        empNumberProperty.SetValue(empNumberProperty, employeeNumber, null);
    }
```

## Full Exception

```
System.Reflection.TargetException : Object does not match target type.
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
TestableEmployee.cs(36,0): at Smack.ConstructionAdmin.TestingSupport.ResourceHelper.SetEmployeeNumberFor(Employee employee, EmployeeNumber employeeNumber)
TestableEmployee.cs(47,0): at Smack.ConstructionAdmin.TestingSupport.ResourceHelperTests.SetEmployeeNumberFor()
```

## EmployeeNumber property code

```
    public virtual EmployeeNumber EmployeeNumber {
        get { return _employeeNumber; } 
        protected set {
            _employeeNumber = value;
            //base.BusinessId = _employeeNumber;
        }
    }
    private EmployeeNumber _employeeNumber;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
empNumberProperty.SetValue(employee, employeeNumber, null);
```

The issue is that the first parameter of SetValue is the object that your trying to modify.

While looking at the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx), I also noticed that this method can throw a `MethodAccessException` if "there was an illegal attempt to access a private or protected method inside a class" which seems like it would apply in this situation. In the remarks section, this notice appears:

> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0 Service Pack 1, this method can be used to access non-public members if the caller has been granted [ReflectionPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.reflectionpermission.aspx) with the [ReflectionPermissionFlag.RestrictedMemberAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.reflectionpermissionflag.restrictedmemberaccess.aspx) flag and if the grant set of the non-public members is restricted to the caller’s grant set, or a subset thereof.
>   To use this functionality, your application should target the .NET Framework version 3.5 or later.

Alternatively, you could try using [`GetSetMethod(bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scfx0019.aspx), but that would still be subject to the same security restrictions.

```
empNumberProperty.GetSetMethod(true).Invoke(employee, new[] { employeeNumber });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
empNumberProperty.SetValue(empNumberProperty, employeeNumber, null);
```

Should be

```
 empNumberProperty.SetValue(employee, employeeNumber, null);
```